# configuring the refer url redirect in spring security

Tags: spring, redirect, spring-security

I am using Spring Security, and I am trying to redirect to a page after login.  If i am logged out, and go to /myurl/home,  I am correctly redirected to the login page.  but when I login, I am redirected to a default URL, not /myurl/home.

I have created a subclass of SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler, and what I am trying to do is if there is a refer in the header, go there,  otherwise go to a default url that I can set.  here is the code:

```
public class MySuccessRedirectHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MySuccessRedirectHandler.class);

private String defaultRedirectUrl;

public MySuccessRedirectHandler(String defaultRedirectUrl) {
    this.defaultRedirectUrl = defaultRedirectUrl;
    this.setUseReferer(true);
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
    String  url = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("referer");
    logger.debug("Referer URL from session:"+url);
    if (url == null) {
        response.sendRedirect(defaultRedirectUrl);
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect(url); 
    }
}
}
```

and my config looks like this:

```
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
         // now start login info
        .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
        .successHandler(new MySuccessRedirectHandler("/home"))
        .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
        .usernameParameter("j_username")
        .passwordParameter("j_password")
        .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true").and()
        // now start logoff info
        .logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").and().exceptionHandling();
```

However,  each time I log in, I get a null for the refer.  How do I get the refer URL so I can get this to work?

Comment: You don*t need a custom `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`. Spring Security  does it by default.

Comment: I know I don't need one.  But I want one as to do other stuff.  I was just trying to get a basic one in place first.

Comment: Then call `super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication)` and try it again.

Comment: Why are you using: `request.getSession().getAttribute("referer");`instead of `request.getHeader("referer")`?